# Is there a way to do --disable-web-security on android chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, security, same-origin-policy

I'm developing a mobile web app where the content server is remote. I can do some basic testing on desktop Chrome with **`--disable-web-security`** option.

*Is there a similar feature available on chrome on android? Or, any other browser on android?*

#### UPDATE

I'm including these headers, `Authorization`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`; but it seems to have no impact on the data server.

*Am I missing any other settings?*

The web app code resides on a local PC. Data on the remote hosts and the browser is on mobile in local LAN.

Comment: Eww. There is a reason why it's called "web security".

Comment: @user2864740 there must also have been a reason to create that command line option.

Comment: Yes, for obscure cases that power-users (or developers) can set on demand after being made aware (hopefully) of the implications. For the general public: no, absolutely not.

Comment: What is the "actual" problem? Could it be solved via a different means? Arguably the correct solutions for CORS would be to have the remote server honor such requests or support JSONP. Also, straight-up requests outside of the browser are not subject to CORS.

Comment: my remote server has a faulty implementation of cors and the fix has other (bigger) issues that will take some time. I am updating the post, may be there is a more intelligent way to handle it....

Comment: @Dinesh did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Michael no, but we got past that stage of development somehow

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way but it is a little hard, first, you should install `adb` on your system (Linux, Windows, macOS and etc) then restart `adb` server and at last plugin your Android device. check the `adb` connection with below command on your terminal/cmd:

```
$ adb list
```

When you see your device on the result of the above command, it is time to run the main command:

```
$ adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

If the above command opens a Google Chrome tab or window, its time to disable security by your command order

Comment: That just loads the Google Chrome app -- the OP is asking about the webview

Comment: @najm, I have successful opening chrome tab, I don't know what does your comment mean.

Comment: Use adb devices instead of  adb list.

Comment: @AmerllicA how can we open google chrome on android device with disabled security option as we do on desktop version of browser using this command: open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security

Comment: @Always_a_learner did you find the command disable cors on chrome on android

Comment: @AmerllicA i was able to open chrome using your second command by putting a ./ on as prefix to the second command. i tried lot of commands to disable cors like but all of them returns not found error